# IMAP enabling a POP3 only E-mail account

Tags: email, imap, pop3

I've currently got an email account with a provider that only allows me to connect using POP3

I would like to use IMAP to access this account.
I can't move email providers

Are there any services that offer IMAP access, but download the emails via pop3, from another account?
I would also need to configure it to send email as well (through the same email address)

Answer (score 5):

[Gmail](http://www.gmail.com). You can use a [Mail Fetcher](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=21288) through Gmail to grab email from your POP3 account, then use [Gmail IMAP](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=75725) to access your email. As a bonus, you can also use [your POP3 provider's SMTP server](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2009/07/send-mail-from-another-address-without.html) through Gmail to send email.

Ack, putting all the links in took too me much time, and someone beat me to the same answer.

**EDIT**
Caveat: You cannot set a time interval for Gmail to fetch your POP3 email. I believe that it sets a time interval based on the frequency at which you receive email in that account. You can, however, fetch mail manually.

Answer (score 1):

GMail allows you to connect to any e-mail account using POP3, and has IMAP access as far as I know.

Plus, it's free.